# Excel VBA for loop a Named List

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column of data day of the week and using a macro to execute a VBA.    Column A is the day of the week and Column B is the name of the object.  When I run the macro, it runs a For loop through a Named List and will populate the items in a calendar on another sheet.  The macro works fine as long as I have the Named List in a fixed length (ie $L2:$A14) so if I add new data, I would need to fix the Named List.

```
Sub UpdateCalendar()
    i = 2
    Dim strRngName As String
    lngLast = Sheets("Servers").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In Application.Range("ScheduledDates")
        strRngName = c.Text
        strUser = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
        User = c.Offset(0, -10).Value
        If (i > 45) Then
        <code stuff>
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried switching line 5 to something like this:

```
For Each c In Sheets("Servers").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row
```

but it doesn't like that (I'm guessing it doesn't see it as a full array?).  The problem with the way this executes is if the "ScheduledDates" field is blank, it will throw an error and stop the script, thus I'm using a fixed length in my Named List.  Not sure if there's any way around this.

Comment: `For Each c In Sheets("Servers").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row` you have a typo in there `x1Up` instead of `xlUp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `dim c as range`, then update your code to:

```
For Each c In Sheets("Servers").Range("L2:L" & Sheets("Servers").cells(Rows.Count,"L").End(xlUp).Row).cells
```

or

```
dim c as range, lLastRow as long
lLastRow=Sheets("Servers").cells(Rows.Count,"L").End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Sheets("Servers").Range("L2:L" & lLastRow).cells
```

You can also update the definition of your named range so it becomes a dynamic named range, either using an `=offset( / counta` structure, of by referencing a `listObject`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column B always has an entry, I prefer this approach:

```
Sub UpdateCalendar()
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim strRngName As String

    Set rng as Sheets("Servers").Range("B2")

    While rng <> ""
        strRngName = rng.Text
        strUser = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value

        '!!!Below line will cause an error in your code as B2 offset by -10 would be B-8!!!
        User = rng.Offset(0, -10).Value

        If (rng.Row > 45) Then
        '<code stuff>

        Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your original code by making the named range dynamic.

For Example, entering the below formula in the 'Refers To' field of the named range selects a range from A2:C where  is the row number of the last filled row.

=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,3)

(assuming data extends from col A to col C with headers in row1)